# Toggle active class using Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the active class of my sections when scrolling through the page. I'm using the intersectionObserver, but am feeling rather stuck with it. I need to get the activeElement from the activeId but am not sure how to do this.

This is de code I've got:

```
const options = {
    threshold: 0.75
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(check, options);

function check(entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const activeId = entry.target.id;
        const activeElement = 

    if(entry.isIntersecting){
        activeElement.classList.toggle("your-active-class");
    };
});
};

sections.forEach(section => {
    observer.observe(section);
});
```

Comment: What are `sections` ? Mind sharing that code just in case?

Comment: `const activeElement = ` ... something's missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `entry.isIntersecting` directly for your `classList.toggle()` second (boolean) argument.
- Use options `{threshold: 0}`, or don't use at all, since *threshold* defaults to `0`

```js
const check = (entries) => entries.forEach(entry => {
  entry.target.classList.toggle("is-active", entry.isIntersecting);
});

const Obs = new IntersectionObserver(check);
document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(el => Obs.observe(el));
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 70vh;
}

.is-active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section style="background: #0bf;">1</section>
<section style="background: #f0b;">2</section>
<section style="background: #fb0;">3</section>
<section style="background: #0fb;">4</section>
```